# Inject middleware after redux store creation

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm wondering if there is a way to inject a Redux store middleware after the store creation?

I'd like to have something like:

```
injectMiddleware(store, [middleware1, middleware2]);
```

In a similar way, we can replace the root reducer on the fly after the store creation with `replaceReducer` https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#replaceReducer.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use Redux to dynamically alter a store's middleware. However a library called [redux-dynamic-middlewares](https://github.com/pofigizm/redux-dynamic-middlewares) does exist to achieve this.

Using this library you can add/remove/clear a store's middleware using calls such as:

```
// will add middleware to existing chain
addMiddleware(myMiddleware /*[, anotherMiddleware ... ]*/)

// will remove middleware from chain (only which was added by `addMiddleware`)
removeMiddleware(myMiddleware)

// clean all dynamic middlewares
resetMiddlewares()
```